# Script to export all Google Drive directories and filenames to a spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to write a script to export all of my Google Drive files and directories to a spreadsheet.

I have the below script written so far but all it will do is list the files in the root directory.

My directory structure is a bit complicated though, with lots of subdirectories. How can I alter this to go recursively through every subdirectory?

```
function listFilesInFolder(folderName) {

var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Video").next();
var contents = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Video").next().getFiles();

var filename, data, sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1l2GiOAfQlN0gGShLhnpYEjBnkGLIwSuFZK_SWxjYtao");

if (!sheet) { // No active sheet, nothing to do
return;
}

sheet.appendRow(["Name", "Date", "Size"]);

while (contents.hasNext()) {

filename = contents.next();

data = [
  filename.getName(),
  filename.getDateCreated(),
  filename.getSize(),
];

sheet.appendRow(data);

}

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking the [DriveApp documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app), you'll find these two methods:

`getFiles()`

> Gets a collection of all files in the user's Drive.

`getFolders()`

> Gets a collection of all folders in the user's Drive.

If you want all from a folder then you'll have to do it recursively.